# batch convert videos with ffmpeg while copying other files in folder hierarchy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, copy, directory-structure, video-conversion

I have a large video archive in a hierarchical folder structure that includes audio and other files alongside the videos.  I would like to replicate the entire structure onto a different disk while converting the videos with ffmpeg to .mp4 format (original is .mov).  I figured out the settings for converting to .mp4:

```
for f in /path/to/archive/*/*/*.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" –c:v libx264 –preset superfast –crf 18 –pix_fmt yuv420p –coder vlc –refs 1 –qmin 4 –c:a libvo_aacenc –b:a 256k –ar 48000 "${f%.mov}.mp4"; done
```

But now I have no clue how to
(a) place the converted .mp4 file into a parallel folder structure onto a different disk,
(b) also copy other files in the structure over.

The structure looks like this:

```
Archive
    2013-05-01
        2013-05-01_08.51.10
            2013-05-01_08.51.10.mov
            2013-05-01_08.51.10.wav
            2013-05-01_08.51.10.txt
        2013-05-01_09.23.47
            2013-05-01_09.23.47.mov
            2013-05-01_09.23.47.wav
            2013-05-01_09.23.47.txt
            2013-05-01_09.23.47.jpg
            (sometimes there are other files and subdirectories too)
        2013-05-01_09.25.23
            ... 
    2013-05-02
        2013-05-02_08.51.10
            2013-05-02_08.51.10.mov
            2013-05-02_08.51.10.wav
            2013-05-02_08.51.10.txt
    ...
```

Each folder has one video, one wav, one txt, and possibly some other files or subfolders.  I would like to replicate the entire structure while replacing the .mov files with converted .mp4 versions.
Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go some indirect way:
Assumed your root paths are

```
/old
/new
```

Create a folder `/new/old`, then just replicate all files and folders other than `.mov` from `/old` to `/new/old`.

In your ffmpeg commandline, all you need to change is the output filename then:

```bash
"new/${f%.mov}.mp4"
```

You will end up with the whole folderstructure in /new/old. Then you move the stuff from `/new/old` to `/new`, done.

The direct solution might be to add a regex before you execute the ffmpeg command.

E.g. like this

```bash
for f in /old/*.mov; do
    echo "before substitute:$f";
    outputfilename=${f/\/old/\/new};
    echo "after substitute: $outputfilename";
    ffmpeg -i "$f" –c:v libx264 –preset superfast –crf 18 –pix_fmt yuv420p –coder vlc –refs 1 –qmin 4 –c:a libvo_aacenc –b:a 256k –ar 48000 "$outputfilename.mp4"; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the first solution works as described and a small test folder structure.  (BTW the slash needs to come after the "new" in the output filename).  I've `rsync`-ed the folder by excluding the `.mov` files and then done as you suggest.  However, for my actual problem, I unfortunately don't have enough diskspace on the disk holding the `old` folder, so I'd need to create the structure directly on the disk with the `new` folder.  Any way how to do that?

Comment: Nvm.  When going back all the way to the root, I can actually do `for f in Users/me/Test/Archive/*/*/*.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "Volumes/OtherDisk/${f%.mov}.mp4"; done` I will then have the `Users/me/Test/` structure also replicated so still need to manually move it where I want it but it'll be on the other disk, so no space issues.  — I'd nonetheless still be curious about any more direct solutions.

Comment: hmmm what was the problem with my direct solution proposal? ...i corrected it by a working version, let me know if you have troubles with it

Comment: thanks very much for editing the code ... (the previous version produced an error, don't remember what) ... this version works to an extent, but not as expected.  Assuming there is just one `.mov` file and one `.txt` file in the `old` directory, I get the converted `.mov` file called `filename.mov.mp4` in the same directory.  It doesn't copy it into `new` (and neither the `.txt` file).